# suddenly monitor detects no signal -- how to troubleshoot?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I'm using Kubuntu 20.04 and the external monitor I've been using for several months suddenly stopped working.  The external monitor is blacked-out, and when I plug it into my laptop it will for a moment flash a blue screen with message "no signal detected" and then go back to black.

`xrandr --query` says that DP-1 is disconnected.

`lspci -d ::0300 -nnk` shows:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
        Subsystem: Lenovo 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [17aa:21f9]
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915
```

I don't know what else to check or what to do.

Comment: Reboot and in grub menu Advanced Options select the previous kernel version and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: I tried a lower version of 5.4.x as well as 5.3.x and neither of those worked.

Comment: Your Display Port cable is defective, or not fully connected.

Comment: You're right, the monitor port (not the cable itself, actually) seems to have defected.  I didn't even touch it when that happened.  How does that hardware just fail?  The port hadn't even been in use for a year.